# merge every 3rd Hash in Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, merge, hash

Hi I can't find how to merge every 3 hashes of an array.
here is my array of hashes.

```
     [
      {:key1=>"v1"}, {:ky2 => "v2"}, {:key3 => "v3"}, 
      {:key1=>"v4"}, {:ky2 => "v5"}, {:key3 => "v6"},
      {:key1=>"v7"}, {:ky2 => "v8"}, {:key3 => "v9"},..
     ]
```

What I would need is to merge every 3 hashes to look like this :

```
      [
       {:key1=>"v1", :ky2 => "v2", :key3 => "v3"}, 
       {:key1=>"v4", :ky2 => "v5", :key3 => "v6"},
       {:key1=>"v7", :ky2 => "v8", :key3 => "v9"},..
      ]
```

Thank in advance for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do

```
hs = [
      {:key1=>"v1"}, {:ky2 => "v2"}, {:key3 => "v3"}, 
      {:key1=>"v4"}, {:ky2 => "v5"}, {:key3 => "v6"},
      {:key1=>"v7"}, {:ky2 => "v8"}, {:key3 => "v9"}
     ]

hs.each_slice(3).map { |grouped_hs| grouped_hs.inject(:merge) }
# => [{:key1=>"v1", :ky2=>"v2", :key3=>"v3"},
#     {:key1=>"v4", :ky2=>"v5", :key3=>"v6"},
#     {:key1=>"v7", :ky2=>"v8", :key3=>"v9"}]
```

Comment: "a" -> hs, "e" -> "grouped_hs" and &:merge -> :merge and you get my upvote. Or something similar, just a bit more meaningful names ;)

Comment: tokland meant `hs` for the plural "hashes" (array of hashes), not the singular "hash". With `hsh`, which implies a hash, it is rather misleading.

Comment: +1 @Arup If you have the time, I would love an explanation of `inject(:merge)` and why this works.  Purely out of curiosity.

Comment: @franksort [`reduce(sym) → obj`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) - *Combines all elements of enum by applying a binary operation, specified by a block or a symbol that names a method or operator.* So `grouped_hs.inject(:merge)` it means `grouped_hs.inject({}) { |init_hsh,elem_hsh| init_hsh.merge(elem_hsh) }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.flat_map(&:to_a).each_slice(3).map(&:to_h)
  #=> [{:key1=>"v1", :ky2=>"v2", :key3=>"v3"},
  #=>  {:key1=>"v4", :ky2=>"v5", :key3=>"v6"},
  #=>  {:key1=>"v7", :ky2=>"v8", :key3=>"v9"}]
```

[Array#to_h](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) was added in v2.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [
  { :key1=>'v1' }, { :ky2 => 'v2' }, { :key3 => 'v3' }, 
  { :key1=>'v4' }, { :ky2 => 'v5' }, { :key3 => 'v6' },
  { :key1=>'v7' }, { :ky2 => 'v8' }, { :key3 => 'v9' }
]

a.each_slice(3).map{ |e| e.inject(&:merge) }
```